# Inequalities between numerical invariants of nonsingular projective Varieties in positive Characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p, chern-classes

It is well-known that [Miyaoka](http://www.springerlink.com/content/q3v55834r8615281/fulltext.pdf) and [Yau](https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.74.5.1798)-type inequalities do not hold in positive characteristic. In "[a note on Bogomolov-Gieseker’s inequality in positive characteristic](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-64/issue-2/A-note-on-Bogomolov-Giesekers-inequality-in-positive-characteristic/10.1215/S0012-7094-91-06418-5.short)", however, we can find the following

> **Theorem 1.** Assume that $p = \mathrm{char}(k) > 0$. Let $X$ be a $d$-dimensional nonsingular
> projective $k$-variety with an ample line bundle $H$. Let $E$ be a $p$-semistable (with respect to $H$) vector bundle of rank $r$ on $X$. Assume $d \ge 2$. Then we have
> $$(r-1)(c_1(E)^2 \cdot H^{d-2}) \le 2r(c_2(E)\cdot H^{d-2})$$
> if **(1)** $r < 3$ or **(2)** $d = 2$.

My question is, are there similar, further results that relate numerical invariants of a nonsingular projective variety in positive characteristic? In particular, it would help me a great deal if there was one involving also the characteristic $p=\mathrm{char}(k)$ itself.

Comment: Did you have a look at both of Shepherd-Barron's papers in Invent. Math. 106 (1991)? They're about surfaces, but go in the direction you're looking for...

Comment: I had a look, this looks promising, thanks a lot! In particular, Corollary 15 from "Geography for surfaces of general type in positive characteristic" is nice. Of course, I would be very interested in any results for arbitrary dimension (and maybe even without bounds on the rank $r$), but I suppose that's a pipe dream. 

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.